# Best development framework for both desktop and mobile apps which can also be connected to raspberry pi

Tags: web-apps, mobile, raspberry-pi, desktop-environment

I want to develop an app which can be used in mobile phones and desktops and laptops. The app should be compatible to all mobile phone Operating Systems(Android, iOS etc.). The app should also be connected to Raspberry Pi. So please suggest me the best **free framework** for this purpose.

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! "Best" is different for everyone. Please read http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information then fix your question and we will reopen it, thanks!

Comment: "The app should also be connected to Raspberry Pi": What interfaces does the Pi offer? For instance a REST API? Any framework allows you to connect to a REST API.

Comment: https://flutter.dev/